# json value priting by key within if in, but not without

Tags: python, json

Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm streaming data from a server and trying to pull specific values by keys, and they are only working if I first check if the key is present

JSON Example

```
{"time_exchange":"2018-04-04T14:29:53.0847306Z","time_coinapi":"2018-04-04T14:29:53.0847306Z","ask_price":117.1,"ask_size":158.30616728,"bid_size":102.60064,"bid_price":117.09,"symbol_id":"COINBASE_SPOT_LTC_USD","sequence":25388355,"type":"quote"}
```

It prints correctly if I do this:

```
data = json.loads(ws.recv())
if 'ask_size' in data:
 print data['ask_size']
```

But if I do just:

```
data = json.loads(ws.recv())
print data['ask_size']
```

I get a key error:

```
KeyError: 'ask_size'
```

Comment: what happens if you simply `print data` ? are you using python `json` module or a third party module ?

Comment: if I do just "print data" it displays the json, example: {u'symbol_id': u'COINBASE_SPOT_LTC_USD', u'sequence': 23691601, u'time_exchange': u'2018-04-04T14:39:36.7990026Z', u'time_coinapi': u'2018-04-04T14:39:36.7990026Z', u'ask_price': 116.21, u'ask_size': 28.0, u'bid_price': 116.15, u'type': u'quote', u'bid_size': 317.94169746}

Yes, using the python json module, I don't know if I am doing something extremely wrong it's just weird that it will print within if in but not without

Comment: All values are able to be pulled by the key within if in, but I don't want to include unnecessary code, it will always have the keys

Comment: Can't reproduce, both work for me.

Comment: In your second example (throwing a key error), are you sure that you actually receive the json data ? if not can you try `j = ws.recv(); print j; data = json.loads(j)` ?

Comment: It's receiving a string that I'm converting to json with json.loads, so weird 

I also can't reproduce it when setting it as a variable, only when getting the streaming data

Comment: data = json.loads(ws.recv())
  stream = ws.recv()
  data = json.loads(stream)
  print data['bid_price']

allows me to print the value by key, but if I do  
  stream = ws.recv()
  data = json.loads(stream)
  print data['bid_price']

I get the key error again, this is so weird to me

Comment: I appreciate you helping

Comment: Also:   data = json.loads(ws.recv()) 
  print data.get('bid_size')

does work, I will just use this

Comment: The *stated purpose* of the API is such that you will get different data each time, yes? Have you considered that the data you're getting might sometimes include the key and other times not? In particular, if you repeatedly call the API, the server might decide to send you some error JSON the second time, to discourage you from flooding.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem, it was returning "{u'type': u'hearbeat'}" as the first response even when not asking for heartbeat, sorry to have wasted everyone's time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point : neither using an intermediate variable nor checking if the key is present will change the content of the dict. Period. The only effect of checkin the key's presence in the dict is preventing the KeyError when it's missing.

Very obviously, what is happening here is that the key is *sometimes* missing and sometimes not. You can easily check this out with the correct test:

```
data = json.loads(ws.recv())
if 'ask_size' in data:
   print data['ask_size']
else:
   print "'ask_size' not found in %s" % data
```

Comment: You're right. This service first returns "{u'type': u'hearbeat'}" even when not asking for it, how silly of me